# Flutter how to add ink effect on top of an SVG image when clicked

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

This is the current code

```
InkWell(
    child: SvgPicture.asset(image),
    onTap: onTap
),
```

There is an example on flutter documentation wrapping this code with Ink.image. That is only accepting other image types and not svg.

I have tried these two approaches:

```
Stack(
  children: [
    InkWell(
        child: SvgPicture.asset(image),
        onTap: onTap
    ),
  ],
)
```

and

```
Ink(
    InkWell(
        child: SvgPicture.asset(image),
        onTap: onTap
    ),
)
```

But nothing seems to do the trick.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The following solution should work

```
Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Positioned.fill(
          bottom: 0.0,
          child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/note.svg'),
        ),
        new Positioned.fill(
          child: new Material(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: new InkWell(
              splashColor: Colors.blueAccent,
              onTap: () {},
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    )
```

Comment: Could you please check it now.

Comment: It's still not working. Before the behind of the image used to have splash but with this one even that is removed

Comment: this one will add a splash effect over the svg image.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a stack with the svg and on top the ink well:

```
Stack(
  children: [
    SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/svg_image.svg'),
    Material(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {},
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        child: Container(
          width: 45,
          height: 45,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
  ],
);
```